# How to null-terminate the keypad input?

Tags: c++, arduino

i need to use 4x3 keypad to move a bldc motor using servo library. i manage to put the keypad input in a string, but i could not null terminate it. The idea of the code is, i enter a servo value in between 0-180 to move the servo from the keypad. Then the input value is then relayed to the bldc. somehow, how do i terminate the string ??

```
#include "Keypad.h"
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
#include <Servo.h>

// initialize the library with the numbers of the interface pins
LiquidCrystal lcd(A0,A1,A2,A3,A4,A5);
Servo myservo;

const byte ROWS = 4; //four rows
const byte COLS = 3; //four columns
char keys[ROWS][COLS] =
 {{'1','2','3'},
  {'4','5','6'},
  {'7','8','9'},
  {'*','0','#'}
  };
byte rowPins[ROWS] = {9,8,7,6}; //connect to the row pinouts of the keypad
byte colPins[COLS] = {5,4,3}; //connect to the column pinouts of the keypad
int count=0;

Keypad keypad = Keypad( makeKeymap(keys), rowPins, colPins, ROWS, COLS );

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.print("enter:");
    myservo.attach(11);
}


void loop()

{
  char key = keypad.getKey();
  char value[4];
    int i=0;
    if  (key >= '0' && key <= '9')
  {
     value[i]=key;
     i++;
     value[i]= 0 ;
     if ( i = 3)
     {
      value[i] = true;
     }
  }

  if ( key = '#')
   {
    value[i]= true;
    Serial.print(value);
   }

  if (value[i] = true)
  {
    int pos = value[4].toInt;
    myservo.write( value);
  }


}
```

Comment: maybe point out what line is confusing you?  I don't understand your question.

Comment: the line after if(key = '#') onward. How do i make sure the value (0-180) that i have entered be null terminated and then be relay onto the bldc.?

Comment: Well, for starters you cannot enter multiple characters, because there is only one call to `keypad.getKey();`. TBH, forget about the Arduino for now, learn to program on an easier environment first.

Answer (score 1):

You often don't need to terminate a string. If you know the length, that's usually enough. So `keys` is a 4x3 array, and you don't need to terminate any of these 4 strings.

You store one character in `value[4]`. You then do null-terminate it, always at `value[1]`.

Your real problem is that `=` is assignment and `==` is comparison.

Comment: why value[1]?? Aren't they suppose be like this... let assume i wanted to enter the value 123... therefore i have to press number 1,2,and 3 in the keypad. Hence, value[0]=1 , value [1]=2 and value[3]= 3 and value[4]=null-terminate.  then  how to i make sure that 123 is actually the value i wanted to relay to the bldc??

Comment: He does need to null-terminate the string since he is using `Serial.print()` which uses `'\0'` as discriminant to know when to stop printing `chars` on `Serial`. He also over-writes the *existing* null-termination with `value[i] = true` when `'#'` is given as input, right before printing the `char[]` buffer, so there's that.

Answer (score 1):

In your source code you first *null-terminate* your `char[]` array with `value[i] = 0`, but then when `#` is pressed you overwrite that position with `value[i]= true;` right before printing it, and obviously causes problems.

This is a *quick-and-dirty* fix:

```cpp
...

void loop()
{
    static char buffer[4];
    static byte i = 0;

    char key = keypad.getKey();

    // i < 3: prevent buffer overflow
    if  ('0' <= key && key <= '9' && i < 3)
    {
        buffer[i] = key;
        ++i;
    } else if (key == '#' && i > 0) {
        buffer[i] = '\0';              // null-terminate buffer

        Serial.println(buffer);    // debug print ?

        int value = atoi(buffer);
        myservo.write(value);

        i = 0;
    }
}
```

Please notice that in this source code example `#` is *required* to terminate a sequence of digits, and every digit in a sequence after the third one is *ignored*. This does not exactly reassemble your original behaviour, but I think that *consistency* of interaction is to be preferred.

Comment: Mr Patrick... thanks for the sugggestion, however the code you gave can only run value from 110-180... how bout value of 0-100... i tried 30,40, 50....100... the motor won't move... but when i enter 110, 120....123,124......180... the motor run...how do i make sure that the value of 0-100 to run the motor...??

Comment: @rjadkins first, is it printing the right values? whether the motor moves or not, that's an entirely different problem: I simply copied-and-pasted `myservo.write(value)` from your question, I have no idea what motor are you using and therefore what it is supposed to happen when given different input values.

Comment: i'm using a brushless motor... i find out when using arduino, i can move the brushless motor using a servo library, hence the myservo.write(value). using servo library, there is a min and max value 0-180... which is 0 (min value) and 180 (max value). this 0-180 value is the speed that i'm setting for the motor to spin. using your code, it manages to spin the speed of from 110-180. However, when i input the speed in between 0-100... the motor won't spin...so i wondering about that..

Comment: @rjadkins you didn't answer my question: is it printing the correct values on serial monitor?

Comment: @rjadkins then it means that the problem does not lie in my code, but in the *assumptions* you have with the behaviour that the motor should have when given certain inputs. Note that in your code example you pass `char[]` to `write()`, but this function expects its inputs to be of type `int`, so perhaps the behavioural mismatch that you observe here is due to that reason.